# Can't access variables from within the thenEvaluate() function in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, scope, casperjs

I have recently started learning CasperJS and I am trying to log in to YouTube. Here's my current code:

```
// XPathSignInButton is predefined
var Username = 'user123';
var Password = 'pass123';

casper.waitForSelector(xPathSignInButton, function() {
    this.thenEvaluate(function() {
        $('#Email').val(Username);
        $('#Passwd').val(Password);
    });
});
```

The code above does not manipulate the input fields (does not write in them), however if I replace `thenEvaluate()` with `this.fillSelectors()`, the variables are accessed normally and everything executes fine:

```
// XPathSignInButton is predefined
// signInFormSelector is predefined
casper.waitForSelector(xPathSignInButton, function() {
    this.fillSelectors(signInFormSelector, {
        'input[name="Email"]': Username,
        'input[name="Passwd"]': Password
    });
});
```

I first thought that there was a problem with how I called jQuery, but when I replaced the variables with the actual strings like: `$('#Email').val('user123');` and `$('#Email').val('pass123');` - it worked like a charm.

My question is how do I access variables from within the `thenEvaluate()` function. Is it at all possible?

Comment: As an aside: you could use `evaluate()` here instead of `thenEvaluate()`. Also, prefer the `fill()` functions over `evaluate()` (it saves you having to do the extra work shown in Artjom's answer, for starters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of [`evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) is the sandboxed page context. You cannot use variables from the outside (and other way around), you have to explicitly pass them:

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function(username, password) {
    $('#Email').val(username);
    $('#Passwd').val(password);
}, Username, Password);
```

It's also important to note that (from [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!**